# MS-Access Automatically updating data based on another table (Email Blacklist)

Tags: excel, ms-access

I'm setting up a brand new database as a lot of the work we do is on multiple spreadsheets and a lot of the data is duplicated. I have a lot of knowledge with Excel, however, I feel that Access would much better suit the needs of the business and data management.

A large role for many in the business is to send emails/follow-up emails based on criteria, however, we use several services to do this and I need a new method of tracking people/businesses who have 'Opted-out' of email updates, we can export the people who opted out from the different applications and put into a spreadsheet.

I had a little play around with relationships to see if this would work, however, kept getting error along the lines of 'invalid for field type' and although I could do this with a simple countif function in Excel I was wondering if it's possible in Access without VBA.

One of the fields we have for our sponsors/delegates table is email address. I want to know if it is possible to create a new form & table or something to do the following:

1. User loads form, clicks a button and selects spreadsheet with emails in Column A
2. Data from column A is then imported into a blacklist table
3. Access removes duplicates and adds the rest to a blacklist table
4. Access updates sponsor/delegate table field 'opt-out' to yes for any email addresses added to the blacklist table

Edit: Here are 2 screenshots of the separate tables 
[image: Blacklist table]
[image: Sponsor Table]

What I need Access to do is basically tick the box 'opt-out' automatically for all records where the email matches to one in the blacklist

Comment: 1. If spreadsheet is simple enough, set a link. 2. Use INSERT SELECT action SQL. 3. JOIN tables and use UPDATE action SQL. Your question is really too broad.

Comment: I have no experience in SQL at all, What I need Access to do is basically tick the box 'opt-out' automatically for all records where the email matches to one in the blacklist. I can play around with the method to update the blacklist eg import/copy/paste etc.

Comment: How can you use Access and have no experience in SQL? Every query is SQL. Switch query object to SQLView to examine SQL statement. Use query builder to construct SQL actions. You asked for non-VBA option - SQL is it.

Comment: Most of the stuff I do in access uses the basic functions or a wizard to create what I need. I'll have to learn how to use the update function although basic googling doesn't help with multiple criteria.


`UPDATE Sponsors
    SET Opt-Out = 1
    FROM blacklist
    WHERE blacklist.email = sponsors.email;`


Basically If email in sponsors appears in blacklist then the field opt-out in sponsors needs to be updated to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query to update the opt-out field in your **Sponsors** table for all records which have a matching email address in the **Blacklist** table is relatively straightforward, with the matching operation performed by a single `inner join`, e.g.:

```sql
update Sponsors inner join Blacklist on Sponsors.[Email Address] = Blacklist.[Email Address]
set Sponsors.[Opt-Out] = -1
```

Comment: Perfect, this done exactly what I needed it to (just had to rename my fields slightly)